# How to prevent expansion

Tags: bash, command-line, find

My script parameters on the mask and consist parameters for the find tool:

```
$mopt=false
case $1 in
...
    -m|--mask-file)     
            if $mopt; then
                or="-o"
            fi       
            mask+=("$or -name $2 ")
            mopt=true
            shift 2;;
...


find . "${mask[@]}"
=>
+ find . '-name *.cpp -o -name *.txt'
```

Although not expand, but fails because the apostrophes around all parameters.
When the $mask has quotes expands.

If I add quotes already hard at creating parameters for the find tool:

```
$mask+=("$or -name \"$2\" ")
find . {$mask[@]}
=>
+ find . -name '"*.cpp"' -o -name '"*.txt"'
```

-name '' * .cpp '' -o -name '"* .txt"'

Find tool is performed with double quotation marks around the mask and also fails.
If you write a script to manually into script:

```
find . -name "${mask[0]}" -o -name "${mask[1]}"...
```

command is executed correctly, but I need to create a name for the find parameters automatically, so that you can enter a variable number of masks.
How, then find stack the order can be entered:

```
find . $mask ...
```

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent expansion of `*.txt` into a list of files? If so, quote: `'*.txt'`. If not, please edit your question to clarify; as it is, I have a very hard time understanding what you are asking.

Comment: Question is changed.

Answer (score 2):

You want it to be 2 or 3 arguments to find: ("-o"), "-name" and "$2", so that's:

```
mopt=false
case $1 in
...
    -m|--mask-file)     
            "$mopt" || mask+=(-o)
            mask+=(-name "$2")
            mopt=true
            shift 2;;

find . "${mask[@]}"
```